How do I write a Makefile target with a repeated pattern?
I have input files with a certain pattern that generates files with that pattern repeated.
my input files are:
inputs/<pattern>.py

e.g.
inputs/cfg1.py
inputs/cfg2.py

calling python inputs/<pattern>.py generates:
outputs/<pattern>/<pattern>.rpt
outputs/<pattern>/<pattern>.html
outputs/<pattern>/<pattern>.txt

e.g. python inputs/cfg1.py generates
outputs/cfg1/cfg1.rpt
outputs/cfg1/cfg1.html
outputs/cfg1/cfg1.txt

How do I write a make rule for that?
I tried
outputs/%/%.rpt: inputs/%.py
    python $<

but it doesn't work

With GNU make >= 4.3, using grouped targets (&:) and secondary expansion:
I   := inputs
O   := outputs
in  := $(patsubst $I/%.py,%,$(wildcard $I/*.py))
out := $(foreach i,$(in),$(foreach s,rpt html txt,$O/$i/$i.$s))

.PHONY: all
all: $(out)

$O:
    mkdir -p $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$O/%.rpt $O/%.html $O/%.txt &: $I/$$(word 1,$$(subst /, ,$$*)).py | $O
    python $<

Grouped targets (a b c &: p) is a way to indicate that the same run of the recipe creates several targets. It is needed to avoid running the same recipe 3 times for your rpt, html and txt targets.
After the special .SECONDEXPANSION: all rules have their list of prerequisites expanded twice, and the second time the automatic variables, like $* for the stem of a pattern rule, are defined. So, this is a way to add some processing to the list of prerequisites. In your case to transform x/x into x.
After the first expansion the rule above becomes:
outputs/%.rpt outputs/%.html outputs/%.txt &: inputs/$(word 1,$(subst /, ,$*)).py | outputs
    python $<

During the second expansion, for each inputs/x.py, it becomes (step by step):
# step 1:
outputs/x/x.rpt outputs/x/x.html outputs/x/x.txt &: inputs/$(word 1,$(subst /, ,x/x)).py | outputs
    python $<

# step 2:
outputs/x/x.rpt outputs/x/x.html outputs/x/x.txt &: inputs/$(word 1,x x).py | outputs
    python $<

# step 3:
outputs/x/x.rpt outputs/x/x.html outputs/x/x.txt &: inputs/x.py | outputs
    python $<

For completeness, as suggested in another answer, you could obtain the same with eval, the make function that programmatically instantiates make statements. Here is a slightly different version of an eval-based solution:
I   := inputs
O   := outputs
in  := $(patsubst $I/%.py,%,$(wildcard $I/*.py))

.PHONY: all

define my_rule
all: $O/$1/$1.rpt $O/$1/$1.html $O/$1/$1.txt

$O/$1/$1.rpt $O/$1/$1.html $O/$1/$1.txt &: $I/$1.py | $O/$1
    python $$<
endef
$(foreach i,$(in),$(eval $(call my_rule,$i)))

$(addprefix $O/,$(in)):
    mkdir -p $@

Note the $$< instead of $<, it is important, again because of double expansion.

Thanks, this worked great! Luckily I'm at GNU make 4.3.

@MaxBjurling Good to know. But remember maybe that another eval-based solution exists. Indeed eval is more powerful than secondary expansion. There are more complicated situations where it is definitely the right tool.

You can hack something together with $(eval ):
# Create a list of inputs.
override inputs := $(wildcard inputs/*.py)

# A list of output files which we fill below.
override all_outputs :=

# Function to generate the targets for a single set of output files.
override define make_target =
$(eval override _name := $(patsubst inputs/%.py,%,$(input)))
$(eval override _dir := outputs/$(_name))
$(eval override _outputs := $(addprefix $(_dir)/$(_name),.rpt .html .txt))
$(eval override all_outputs += $(_outputs))

$(_outputs) &: $(input) | $(_dir)
    touch $(_outputs)# Your command here.

$(_dir):
    mkdir -p $$@
endef

# Generate the targets:
$(foreach input,$(inputs),$(eval $(make_target)))

# The `all` target.
.PHONY: all
all: $(all_outputs)
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

I also threw in the rules to generate the output directories if your tool doesn't do that automatically.

Just to note this requires GNU Make 4.3 or above, else you'll get failures.

Thanks for the suggestion! I went with the answer from Renaud Pacalet though as it seemed less hacky.

@MaxBjurling Fair enough. You should press the checkmark next to their answer to mark your question as solved.

I did, but I'm not trusted enough by stackoverflow to have my vote being counted publicly. Probably since this is my first question posted.

Aha, checkmark, not upvote. Now I did that too...
